# How to disable changes in a cell using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with the bellow code:
This code do for Example: If I input any value in cell A1, cell B1 display a time stamp.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
       If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Range("B1:B10"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
           If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
               .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
           Else
               With .Offset(0, 1)
                   .NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
                   .Value = Now
               End With
           End If
           Application.EnableEvents = True
       End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

What I am trying to do now is to protect/not editable from the user the cell "B1:B10" once time stamp has made by the macro. I google on how to protect but I am having hard time to insert those code I found. Can anyone help me how I construct/insert this code to my original code?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'set your criteria here
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        'must disable events if you change the sheet as it will
        'continually trigger the change event
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        MsgBox "You cannot do that!"
    End If
    End Sub
```

Or this code:

```
    'select the cell you want to be editable
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C3").Locked = False
    'then protect the entire sheet but still vba program can modify instead.
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Thanks to Kazjaw. Here is the final code.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    'Protect cell "B1:B10"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Locked = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:b10").Locked = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=Tru

    With Target
       If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Range("B1:B10"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
           If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
               .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
           Else
               With .Offset(0, 1)
                   .NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
                   .Value = Now
               End With
           End If
           Application.EnableEvents = True
       End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to protect only Range B1:B10 then you need to run this sub **only once**:

```
Sub ProtectCellsInB()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Locked = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:b10").Locked = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

I made a modification- I added a password to protection which you can delete.

If you are not sure how to run it **once** then you could add the whole internal code at the end of your `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)`

Comment: Hi KazJaw, your suggestion is perfectly work for what I want to. Thank you for answering my question. I will post my code soon for documentation purposes.

Comment: Opps! I almost forgot. Thank you again.