# How to lock specific cells in VBA but leave them editable by code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some cells that are filled by some formula created in VBA script.
I want to make them not-editable (locked) by user input but let the script fill them with formulas.

I tried by protecting worksheet with a password and then :

```
Range.locked = True
```

But this didn't allow the code to edit the  cells..

Comment: I Think you might read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016258/11167163), once you tried it if it still doesn't work please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58101335/edit) your issue.

Comment: How are you populating the cells in code? Using cells(x,y)= value?

Comment: In the spirit of IT... *Have you tried turning it off and back on again?*  This would actually work for your code, to set `=false` at the start of your code, then `=true` as the last step in your code.

Comment: @Blingers I use this : myRow.Offset(0, 1).FormulaArray = variableThatContainsFormulaString

Comment: @Cyril i will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting cells in Excel but allow these to be modified by VBA script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/protecting-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Protect` the sheet with `UserInterfaceOnly` parameter:

```
MyWorksheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly := True
```

where `MyWorksheet` is a valid reference of your worksheet object

Comment: Would be nice if you add your [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126032/11167163)

Comment: @Dorian, my actual source is my code templates. On their turn some of them are by myself and some by "external" code. But I mostly do not keep track of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
myRow.Offset(0, 1).FormulaArray = variableThatContainsFormulaString 
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Obvs prob better replacing active sheet with your actual sheet but you get the idea.

Looks like this has the available solutions though... [Protecting cells in Excel but allow these to be modified by VBA script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/protecting-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script?rq=1)